# Can "in the order" be used instead of "sequentially"?

Tags: adverbs

Are two sentences bellow equivalent?

> 1. Post blocks have executed in the order.
> 2. Post blocks have executed sequentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sequentially" and "in order" essentially mean the same thing.

The only thing wrong with the first sentence is that it doesn't need "the".

> Post blocks have executed in <s>the</s> order.

"The" refers to something in particular, so it must be clear what you are referring to. *The* order? Which order?

Arguably you don't need the word "*have*" in there either, depending on context.

Of course, this assumes that the reader is already aware what that order is, either because you previously stated it, or you are able to assume that they know. Otherwise, you should state the order:

> Post blocks executed in ascending order.

A situation where you *would* include "the" would be if you were referring to a particular order, for example:

> Post blocks executed in the correct order.

or

> Post blocks executed in the order expected.

---

Your second sentence:

> Post blocks have executed sequentially.

This seems fine, again the word "have" may not be needed, depending on context. The word *sequentially* denotes a specific order but does not say what that order is, so the reader would either be expected to know what that sequence or order is, or understand that it is not necessary to know.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Astralbee's comment about the word "the":

"Sequentially" denotes "one after another" -- so "executed sequentially" implies that one finished executing before another one started executing. It does not imply anything about the order -- for all we know, perhaps they executed in a wrong order.

"In order" implies "in the correct order" if you don't specify any particular order.

Comment: I disagree. Dictionary defines "sequentially" as: "by forming or following a *logical order or sequence*". I think you may have confused it with the word "consecutively".

Comment: Also the word "executed" implies completion, especially in this context which I believe is programming. So they completed in order no matter what word you use to describe the order.